# How to mock call to constructor of class in 3rd party module called from the same module using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, ts-jest

I have a 3rd party module like this

```
class Test {
   async doSomething() {}
}

export const testObject = new Test();  <--- I want to mock this part because constructor requires some input which I don't want to provide as it is not required for tests
```

another module which imports the above module

```
import { testObject } from 'module1';

function foo() {
    testObject.doSomething()
}
```

Now I am trying to write unit tests like below

```
describe('test', ()=> {
    test('', ()=> {
        foo()
    })
})
```

`new Test()` depends on some outside input which I don't want to provide so when i run tests, it fails because of missing input and I am not sure how to stop `new Test()` from being executed as is and instead a mock functions should be run instead

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. If you run this test it'll pass:

Class file.

```
class SoundPlayer {
  foo: string
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'bar'
  }

  playSoundFile(fileName: any) {
    console.log('Playing sound file ' + fileName)
  }
}

export const testObject = new SoundPlayer()
```

Function file

```
import { testObject } from './test'

export default function test() {
  testObject.playSoundFile('testing')
}
```

Test file

```
import { testObject } from '../test'
import test from '../test1'
jest.mock('../test')

it('should run test', () => {
  test()
  expect(testObject.playSoundFile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

This is a very basic example and there are 4 different ways you can mock.
Check out the Jest documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#the-4-ways-to-create-an-es6-class-mock

Comment: I don't want to mock any method on testObject though. I want to mock call to constructor of Test class. But I am not calling the constructor. It gets called inside the module  by this line `export const testObject = new Test();` and I want to mock this call because constructor is taking input which i don't want provide as that functionality is not required by tests

Comment: What have you tried so far? When you say third-party do you mean it's an npm module? If not, is it possible to not export the result of the constructor? That you you can mock the constructor instead of mocking the result of the constructor.